# Importing mongo collection into existing collection without overriding it

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport, mongodump

Is it possible to import a mongodump into a existing collection adding to it (not overriding it)? If yes, how?

Would it be using `mongoimport --db mydb`?

The collections are the same in structure but simple have different datasets from different instances of the same app. I'd like to merge all data into a single database.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [mongorestore](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/).

It is overwriting the collection only if you specify [--drop](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/#cmdoption--drop) parameter. So if you do nothing it will just add new element (thus doing what you want).

The only problem might arise if you have the same `_id` elements, in which case it will just ignore them.

> If you restore to an existing database, mongorestore will only insert
>   into the existing database, and does not perform updates of any kind.
>   If existing documents have the same value _id field in the target
>   database and collection, mongorestore will not overwrite those
>   documents.