# Duplicate object Id Mongo db while import/export from two db's into a central db

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport, mongoexport

I am having two mongo instances running on two different environments(client). I have a central database(server) where the data from all the clients will be saved.I am using use [mongorestore](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/#bin.mongorestore) and [mongodump](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongodump/#bin.mongodump) for exporting the data .I have doubt whether there is a possibility that same object id might be present in both of the client databases. What will happen if I export those data?? Will the old data will be overridden ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Importing mongo collection into existing collection without overriding it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29740348/importing-mongo-collection-into-existing-collection-without-overriding-it)

Comment: In that answer I explained what will happen in case of a duplicate.